# How to allow multiple Hudson jobs with same name to run

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, hudson-plugin-batch-task

I have a Hudson job with 2 tasks.  If I start task A and then start task B while task A is still running, then task B will not start running until task A has finished.  I have no locking on this job (i.e. "Locks" option is not ticked).  How do I enable this job so that task A and task B will run simultaneously?

Comment: So are you trying to run the same job twice, or do you have two jobs with the same name, or are you trying to run task A at the same time as task B (what is a task?) and it does not work?

Comment: They are "batch tasks" which are like subsections of your build job.  They appear when you install the Batch Task plugin (http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Batch+Task+Plugin).  So job "BUILDME" has two batch tasks - buildme-a and buildme-b.  What I want to be able to do is have buildme-a and buildme-b run simulataneously.  But at present, Hudson runs one, waits till its finished, and then runs the other.

Answer (score 0):

The Batch Tasks plugin treats tasks as basically steps in a queue so, at present, I doubt you can have them run simulataneously.

If you want two tasks to run simultaneously (all the time?), when not just put those tasks as external scripts and then create a task to run them both at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Normal builds and batch jobs have an implicit lock on the workspace - you wouldn't want the build to start in the middle of your batch job and wipe out the workspace, so this make sense.   You could argue for a selection between shared and exclusive workspace locking when running the batch jobs.
At present, it's always exclusive, as you've noticed.